# Easy way of integrating the same integrand over several intervals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, custom-notation

I was wondering if there is some shorthand in Mathematica for expressions such as

$$\left(\int_A + \int_B + \int_C + \cdots\right)F(x_1,\ldots, x_n) dx_1\cdots dx_n$$

where $A,B,C,\ldots$ each denote some integration region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F$ is the integrand, common to all integrals.

Comment: if A, B, C, are disjoint, you can use `Integrate[F[x1,...,xn],{x1,..,.xn}\[Element] RegionUnion[A,B,C]`?

Comment: @kglr This is only true of $A$, $B$, and $C$ are pairwise disjoint...

Comment: @Henrik,  right.

Comment: Have you seen `RegionUnion[]`?

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-Mathematica, I would write

```
Total[Integrate[f[x1,x2,xn],#]&/@{A,B,C}]
```